# Base64 and mcrypt_encrypt in android

Tags: php, android, encryption, base64, nosuchmethoderror

I need to encrypt in android a certain text using a secret key. In PHP the encryption code looks like this

```
$this->securekey = hash('sha256',$textkey,TRUE);
$this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
```

For Base64 I added the commons codec from apache.org (commons-codec-1.6.jar) in Netbeans for my Android application. There is no error in the code. But when I run the application and call the function that use the codec the application stop and need a fore close.

In the logCat says:

```
Android Runtime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64
```

Here is my code :

```
public static String crypt(String input, String key){
            byte[] crypted = null;
            try{
                SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(key), "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
                crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
           return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(crypted);
        }
```

I am not sure if my code do the same encryption as the PHP code. I found this link http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php between Android and PHP but it doesn't use Base64, just for mcrypt_encrypt. Can anyone help me to obtain the same encryption as the PHP server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, I would not trust "android snippets" for cryptography related information if my life depended on it. Horrible stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is simply because you forgot to add the Apache codec library to your runtime environment. Just compiling against it is not enough; the library needs to be actually *present* on the Android device.

You cannot get the same encryption on Android using the default Java libraries, you probably require the Bouncy Castle library. The PHP code in your example uses Rijndael with a block size of 32 bytes. AES is a subset of Rijndael with block sizes of 16 bytes. This is known as `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` in PHP mcrypt.

Some other implementation details:

- ECB does not use an IV (by now I've replaced the default mcrypt_encrypt sample by something better);
- mcrypt_encrypt does not perform PKCS5Padding, I think it uses spaces;
- `input.getBytes()` is not portable, it uses the platform default encoding, which may be different from the PHP encoding;

Finally some security warnings:

- just using SHA-256 on passwords is considered insecure, use PBKDF2;
- ECB is considered insecure, use CBC;
- `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` is not secure (which basically means PHP encryption is worthless, you are better off using a PHP openssl wrapper);

Good luck!

Comment: Did this answer not help you Gabrielle? Do you need more information?

Comment: I've suddenly received a -1 on this answer. I don't mind downvotes - even ones I don't agree with - as long as it is clear to my why the downvote occured.